# Add input parameter VS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS. I have Business Intelligence VS 2008. I am trying to add report parameters to the report but the data tab  does not seem to be coming up in the designer. My requirement is to pass parameters from the UI to the report in a remote/server mode. I have to just pass the parameters to the report and the report should render the output in a pdf format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you're looking for.  Take a look at the following link: http://weblogs.asp.net/stephensonger/archive/2008/12/05/opening-ssrs-report-in-pdf-format-via-asp-net.aspx

It outputs an SSRS 2008 report directly to PDF.